# Evaluate the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Does this limit equals 0 or it doesn't exist ?

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2 \sin(x)\cos(y)}{x^2 + y^2} $$

What I have done already :

$$
\quad 0\leq\frac{y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \leq 1 \\ 0\sin(x)\cos(y) \leq \frac{y^2 \sin(x)\cos(y)}{x^2 + y^2} \leq \sin(x)\cos(y) \\ 0 \leq \frac{y^2 \sin(x)\cos(y)}{x^2 + y^2} \leq \sin(x)\cos(y) 
$$

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 0 = \lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}\sin(x)\cos(y) = 0 \\  so  ,\quad \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2 \sin(x)\cos(y)}{x^2 + y^2} = 0
$$
If this isn't valid , let me know

EDIT :
Now I see it isn't valid but about using  $$\mid \sin(x)\cos(y) \mid $$ instead $$ \sin(x)\cos(y)$$ ?

Comment: You can't just multiply through inequalities with functions that can be both positive and negative. Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ have image $[-1,1]$, the best you can have is $-1 \leq \frac{y^2 \sin x \cos y}{x^2+y^2} \leq 1$

Comment: in order to get positive values (and hence to allow multiplication, cf infra) a good solution is to put $|.|$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it without polar coordinates for sake of variety. Let $h = (x,y)$.

Then, 
\begin{align*}
|\lim_{|h| \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^2\cdot \sin(x)\cdot \cos(y)}{x^2+y^2}| 
=& \lim_{|h| \rightarrow 0} |\frac{y^2\cdot \sin(x)\cdot \cos(y)}{x^2+y^2}| \\
\leq& \lim_{|h| \rightarrow 0} |\frac{y^2\cdot x}{x^2+y^2}| \\
\leq& \lim_{|h| \rightarrow 0} |\frac{(x^2+y^2)\cdot x}{x^2+y^2}| \\
\leq& \lim_{|h| \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0.
\end{align*}

The proof follows. Note that the first step follows by continuity of $|.|$ and the second from $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ by Taylor's Theorem and $|\cos(y)| \leq 1$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to polar coordinates, $x \to r\cos \theta, \; y \to r\sin \theta$,  simplifies this a lot.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ y^2 \sin x \cos y }{ x^2+y^2 } =& 
\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{ r^2 (\sin^2 \theta) \sin(r\cos \theta) \cos(r\sin \theta)}{r^2} \\ 
=&
\lim_{r \downarrow 0} (\sin^2 \theta )\sin(r\cos \theta) \cos(r\sin \theta) \\
=&
(\sin^2 \theta )\sin(0) \cos(0) \\
=& \sin^2 \theta \cdot 0 \cdot 1 \\
=& 0.
\end{align*}